# Magento 2.2.6 - frontend and admin blank after setup:di:compile

Tags: magento, permissions, magento2, php-7.1, magento2.2

I've seen similar questions on here but none solve the problem for me. I hoping someone can help me solve/investigate/debug this problem.

I have Magento 2.2.6 installed on a Ubuntu 18.02 with LAMP (PHP 7.1). I had the store up and running and all was going well. I have the free Pixtron theme from HiddenTechies installed.

When trying to configure Braintree payments, I read something that told me to run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` (I can't remember why).

After that command ran, everything is totally blank. When I go to the frontend and admin login in a web browser, they are blank. The page source for either doesn't have any content.

I tried a bunch of commands like `setup:upgrade` and `cache:flush` but nothing helps. This happened previously and I ended up wiping the server and starting from scratch, but that isn't a long-term solution.

I have a suspicion that the issue may related to permissions because I don't fully understand what I'm doing with them (I'm learning). Maybe there's a way to do a permissions "health check".

Any advice/pointers in the right direction appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Gve full permission for app, var, pub/static, generated.
From your root folder, run this command
`chmod -R 777 app/ var/ pub/static/ generated`

Answer (score 1):

You can try running static-content deploy command for the store ,And also please check console for errors.

php/bin setup:static-content:deploy en_US

Where en_US is the store